# HTML: converting iso-8859-1 encoded smart quotes to simple quotes in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to parse and clean an HTML file with Python 3. I'm using BeautifulSoup's get_text method, with lxml as the parser (along with urllib etc.)

Given such text as `you’ve` in the iso-8859-1 encoded HTML, with its "smart" apostrophe/quote, I'm having trouble getting a clean text, such that it becomes `you've`.

I've tried putting it through utf-8 and back again, but it makes a mess of the text.

Part of the class:

```
   self.html = response.read()
   self.html_parser = BeautifulSoup(self.html, "lxml")
   decodedStr = self.html.decode('iso-8859-1')
   encodedByt = decodedStr.encode('utf-8')
   table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys([0x201c, 0x201d, 0x2018, 0x2019]))
   encodedStr = str(encodedByt).translate(table)
   self.html = encodedStr.encode('iso-8859-1')
```

There are non-Ascii characters, "you`<0x92>`ve" -- so quopri didn't work for me.

I'm just learning Python and would appreciate suggestions on doing this in a more idiomatic or better way. Thanks.

UPDATE:

This helps; it seems that `str` needs encoding to be specified (except for the ellipsis, these are getting translated)

```
   transl_table = dict( [ (ord(x), ord(y)) for x,y in zip( u"‘’´“”–-…",  u"'''\"\"--\u2606") ] ) 
   encodedStr = str(encodedByt, 'utf-8').translate(transl_table)
   self.html = encodedStr.encode('utf-8', 'strict')
```

Comment: Did you tried `BeautifulSoup(self.html, from_encoding="iso-8859-1")` ?

Comment: Yes, the text becomes `youve` with that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
table = str.maketrans({'’': "'"})
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll explore this also. And this works for my ellipsis problem, thanks again.